# What exactly are the "race conditions" of multiple celery processes writing to a single log file?

Tags: celery

In the [celery docs for v4.4.0](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.4.0/userguide/daemonizing.html#available-options) among other versions, there is the following warning in the section explaining how to configure the log file:

> CELERYD_LOG_FILE - Full path to the worker log file. Default is /var/log/celery/%n%I.log Note: Using %I is important when using the prefork pool as having multiple processes share the same log file will lead to race conditions.

What exactly are these race conditions? I've tried to replicate any sort of issue by creating a simple task that writes a bunch of logs, and executing the task across multiple pre-fork workers simultaneously hundreds of times. The log messages are interleaved, as expected, and I see no indication of problematic behavior.

Comment: The interleaved messages *are* the result of the race condition: you can't predict the order in which the processes will write the file. However, each logging operation is not atomic; although you observe each one written in full, that isn't guaranteed. You could see half of log message from process 1, then the entire log message from process 2, *then* the rest of the original log message from process 1 as well.

Comment: I guess what I mean by "as expected" is that the order of the messages looks normal: the timestamps only ever increase, there is no instance of timestamps being "out of order." As for messages being "broken up," I'm not seeing that either - every log message seems to stay complete and unbroken. Am I just being insanely lucky, or am I missing something sinister?

Comment: You are probably being lucky, and maybe you never *will* have a problem. The documentation is just stating that the possibility *exists* for it to not work the way you currently observe or expect; race conditions are inherently nondeterministic.